# The coating on the pots

Tags: word-request

What do we call the type of layer on pots? The layer which is shiny, is called:

1. ceramic
2. glossy
3. smooth
4. glassy

Comment: glossy, smooth, and glassy are adjectives, so they describe what the coating looks or feels like, but they are not the coating themselves. Many coatings are all three (glossy and glassy and smooth). If this were a multiple choice test, I'd pick ceramic, because its the only noun.

Comment: Are you asking for a noun or adjective? Regardless, you need to be much more precise. Pots can be made of more than a single substance, and they can be described in more than one way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the glaze on a ceramic pot. The glaze is usually glossy, smooth and glassy.  "Ceramic" is a noun, and the glaze is glass, not a typical ceramic.